# Create comma-delimited values in Excel (using PivotTable)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, denormalization, csv

Is there a way to generate comma-delimited values in Excel (optimally using a PivotTable)?  Consider the following data:

```
Object Color
foo    Red
foo    Blue
bar    Red
bar    Blue
bar    Green
baz    Yellow
```

I'd like to get a table like the following:

```
Object  Count of Color  Colors
foo     2               Red,Blue
bar     3               Red,Blue,Green
baz     1               Yellow
```

Is this possible in Excel?  The data is coming from a SQL query, so I could write a UDF with a recursive CTE to calculate, but this was for a single ad-hoc query, and I wanted a quick-and-dirty way to get the denormalized data.  In the end, it's probably taken longer to post this than to write the UDF, but...

Comment: A much simpler solution:

http://superuser.com/questions/249437/excel-pivot-values-in-one-cell-as-comma-separated-value

Comment: A much simpler solution here:

http://superuser.com/questions/249437/excel-pivot-values-in-one-cell-as-comma-separated-value

Comment: @yioann Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a much simpler answer, adapted from [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/249788/147853) (HT to [@yioann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179851/yioann) for pointing it out and [@F106dart](https://superuser.com/users/55392/f106dart) for the original):

Assuming the data is in columns A (Category) and B (Value):

1. Create a new column (C), and name it "Values". Use this formula, starting in cell C2 and copying all the way down: `=IF(A2=A1, C1&","&B2, B2)`
2. Create a second new column (D), and name it "Count". Use this formula, starting in cell D2, and copying all the way down: `=IF(A2=A1, D1+1, 1)`
3. Create a third new column (E), and name it "Last Line?". Use this fomula, starting in cell E2, and copying all of the way down: `=A2<>A3`

You can now hide column B (Value) and filter column E (Last Line?) for only the `TRUE` values.

In summary:

```
   A         B      C                        D                    E
 +---------  -----  -----------------------  -------------------  ----------
1| Category  Value  Values                   Count                Last Line?
2| foo       Red    =IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)  =IF(A2=A1, D1+1, 1)  =A2<>A3
3| foo       Blue   =IF(A3=A2,C2&","&B3,B3)  =IF(A3=A2, D2+1, 1)  =A3<>A2
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would be much better off using the tools of whatever RDBMS you're running (MS SQL, MySQL, etc.).

Such a pivot table is *possible* in Excel. But, only if you write a cumbersome VBA module -- which I don't recommend.

However, the task is simpler in MS Access -- which usually comes bundled with Excel.   Microsoft makes it "easy" to link Access and Excel and to use the former to run queries on the latter.
So, given the spreadsheet cells as stated:

1. For best results, sort the table by `Object` and then by `Color`.
2. Make sure the spreadsheet is saved.
3. Open up MS Access.
4. Select *File --> Open*   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>)
5. Under *Files of type*, select ***Microsoft Excel***
6. Navigate to and choose your existing spreadsheet.
7. Choose the worksheet or named range that contains your table.
8. Give the linked table the name `MyPivot`.
9. Open the Visual Basic Editor... *Tools --> Macro --> Visual Basic Editor*   (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>)
10. Insert a module and paste in this UDF:

    ```
    'Concat returns a comma-seperated list of items
    Public Function Concat (CategoryCol As String, _
                            ItemCol     As String) As String
        Static LastCategory As String
        Static ItemList     As String

        If CategoryCol      = LastCategory Then
            ItemList        = ItemList & ", " & ItemCol
        Else
            LastCategory    = CategoryCol
            ItemList        = ItemCol
        End If
        Concat = ItemList
    End Function
    ```
11. Save the project and close the VB editor
12. Under *Queries*, Create a new query in design view.
13. Switch to the ***SQL View***.
14. Paste in this SQL:

    ```
    SELECT 
        Object,
        COUNT (Color)                  AS [Count of Color],
        LAST (Concat (Object, Color))  AS [List 'O Colors]
    FROM
        MyPivot
    GROUP BY
        Object
    ```
15. Run the query (Press the red exclamation mark or just select the *Datasheet View*).
16. Voilà, done in 15 easy steps!    ;)
    Results:

    ```
    Object  Count of Color  List 'O Colors
    bar             3       Blue, Green, Red
    baz             1       Yellow
    foo             2       Blue, Red
    ```

Comment: Wow, that was intense.  I'll edit the OP with a UDF to do the same in SQL if I ever get some free time.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

An even easier way is to add the data to the data model when you create the pivot table and then use a "measure" (called "Colours") as follows:

```
=CONCATENATEX(Table1,[Color],", ")
```

Then add the "Colours" field to the values portion of the pivot.